# how to add if conditions in orWhere db query - laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8

I am having search function as :

```
 if (!empty($searchText)) {
            $customer->join('details', 'customers.details_id', '=', 'details.id');
            $customer->where('name', 'like', "%$searchText%")
                     ->orWhere("details.product", "like", "%$searchText%")
        }
```

I am having column in DB table "owner id" , and in UI table there is column "show Me"
if owner id is assigned "show me" option shows up else there is no optopn in the column(empty)

for search function i need if , anyone search for "show me" only  assign owner will get search ,

so how can i add where condition to check if searchtext box contains show me , then only assigned owner id will get searched

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> **Change Your code from these**

```
if (!empty($searchText)) {
        $customer->join('details', 'customers.details_id', '=', 'details.id');
        $customer->where('name', 'like', "%$searchText%")
                 ->orWhere("details.product", "like", "%$searchText%")
    }
```

> **To These**

```
if (!empty($searchText)) {
        $customer->join('details', 'customers.details_id', '=', 'details.id');
        $customer->where(['name', 'like', "%$searchText%"],["details.product", "like", "%$searchText%"])
    }
```

Comment: I need to add seperate condition for that , if in db owner id column is having value as 1 and someone searched "show me"  then the flag = 1 values from db will shown. @HeroCode